# Find at least one solution to matrix inequality

Tags: linear-programming, matrix-equations, geometric-inequalities

I have the following problem posed: 
find at least one vector $\mathbf{x}$ such that
$$
A\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b} \geqslant \mathbf{0}
$$
for a given matrix $A$ and vector $\mathbf{b}$. Nothing is known about dimensions of the matrix. You may assume the set of solutions for this problem is non-empty and that the rank of the matrix is complete, i.e. $\mbox{rk}(A) = \mbox{min}(m, n)$. The inequality is understood as applied component-wise.

Do you know any algorithm capable of solving such problem? I checked textbooks on linear programming, but found nothing specifically dealing with this problem. Thanks for any comments!

Comment: You could always just solve $A \mathbf x = - \mathbf b$, which evidently gives you an $\mathbf x$ that satisfies the wanted inequality.

Comment: @MisterRiemann what if $A$ is non-square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the linear optimization problem
$$\min_{x} \{ 0^Tx : Ax \geq b\}.$$
This can be solved in many ways. Let me name 3:

1. An infeasible interior point method. This solves 
   $$\min_{s\geq 0, x} \{ 0^Tx : Ax - s = b\}.$$
2. A feasible interior point method. Consider the extended linear optimization problem:
   $$\min_{x,y\geq 0} \{ e^Ty : Ax+b+y \geq 0\}.$$
   A feasible starting point for this problem is $x=0$, $y=\max\{0,-b\}$.
3. With the two phase simplex method in which you only need the first phase. This is essentially solving 
   $$\min_{x^- \geq 0,x^+\geq 0, y \geq 0} \{ c^Ty : A(x^+-x^-) + By \geq b\},$$
   where $B$ is a diagonal matrix with $B_{ii}=1$ if $b_i\geq 0$, $-1$ otherwise, and $c_i=1$ if $b_i\leq 0$, $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I just found the mention of two-phase approach before reading your answer. I'll take a look at all three.

Comment: @MajinSaha did it answer your question?

Comment: Yes. I wish there was a shorter way, but I guess that's the best one out there.

Answer (score 0):

Linear programming is your method of choice.

A good way to visualize what is going on is to consider the rows of $A$ as vectors $A_i$. So you have a set of inequalities $ A_i x + b_i \geq 0$. Each of these inequalities defines a halfspace in $n$-dimensional space, with a boundary which is a hyperplane with normal vector  $A_i$ and distance from the origin   $b_i/ |A_i|$. Your matrix inequality equation is then the intersection of all of these   halfspaces. If the intersection is not empty, the intersection space is a polyhedron.

Finding an $x$ is exactly the question whether this intersection is empty or not.  In linear programming, this  is called "interior point method" (you find it on wikipedia and elsewhere) and it is a well-known procedure for finding a feasible point to start any optimization procedure (which you do not have).

Comment: Yes, I read about IP approach before. Currently, I'm only aware of a method to initialize a feasible starting point for IP for a linear program $\mbox{min} (\mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{x})$, but such method requires the information on $\mathbf{c}$. It minimizes some simple quadratic and involves lagrange multipliers to present the starting point for the IP opimization. My question though is a bit general, and I don't know how to use that for my case.

Comment: This is not called "interior point method". An interior point method is an optimization method, not a method to find a feasible point. On the contrary: they need a starting point within the interior.

Comment: I am aware of that. I probably didn't explain clearly what I meant. Anyways, thanks for commenting.

Comment: Well, as I explained, you are looking for an interior point in a polyhedron (if it exists). So you may choose a point at the boundary  of such polyhedron which  is the intersection of at most $n$ halfplanes which are not linearly dependent, so such a point obeys the halfplane constraints with equality. If the number $m$ of constraints is larger than $n$, then the remaining constraints must be satisfied with inequality. Only then (if it fails)  may there be a problem. So, use an active set method or use slack variables as Phase I of this IP problem to check feasibility.